# How to simulate a real camera with blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, camera, units

I have a camera with a fisheye lens. I need to simulate it on blender to get the same images

camera properties:
sensor size: 2/3".
image resolution: 1360*1024 
fisheye focal: 1.8mm
H*V (FOV): 185*185 (with 2/3").
here is the link for the fisheye lens [fisheyelens](http://view.samurajdata.se/psview.php?id=e032901e&page=1) and the camera [GC1380](http://1stvision.com/cameras/AVT/Prosilica-GC1380-GC1380C.html)

My problems is how to fix the V field of view ? I have chose a fisheye equisolid and I set a focal length as 1.8 and the FOV =185 as H filed of view. But the horizontal field of view is determined by the W/H image resolution which different to 1 in  the real case. Any help?

Comment: Which camera and what lens do you use?

Comment: @poor, All details are in the question (line 2).

Comment: Yeah, but I meant which real camera (model, manufacturer), lens (model, manufacturer)?

Comment: @poor, sorry, I added the links

Comment: Might be worth having a look at http://www.luxrender.net/ - it isn't officially supported for latest Blender 2.7x but I have seen forum posts suggesting that it does.

Comment: @Neil, Fisheye is supported by 2.7x in the cycle engine!!

Comment: I see you really want this answered, can you post some picture from the camera and some render you are getting and how they differ? This will help a little with answering (I don't have that camera). These images would be best of some grid like pattern.

Comment: @startingBlender  FYI....the first link on your post is broken.

Comment: In addition to @cegaton's nice answer: It really depends on what do want to achieve - as always... But if you have to match it with a plate, I suggest you to consider **lens distortion** for accuracy.

Comment: @poor, what is the difference between what I did and the solution of cegaton. He just put the images that describe my solution.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, What else you need?

Answer (score 8):

Looking at the specs form the [manufacturer](http://www.sony.net/Products/SC-HP/new_pro/may_2014/icx825_e.html) you can see the dimensions of the sensor:

[image]

Using simple math you can determine the sensor's active area to be 8.78mm wide and 6.61mm tall.

Input those on the vertical and horizontal size values for the sensor and create a preset for future use.

[image]

Set the lens and field of view. to 1.8mm and 185 degrees.

[image]

Now set the render size on your scene to the dimensions of your camera:

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between your solution and  my configuration. I have done the same thing! I think that it have to change the aspect ratio to get the right angle.

Comment: your calculation of the sensor size is not true. the size sensor is 6.6*8.8 which  gives 11mm as diagonal size

Comment: 11mm diagonally is what sony lists as the sensor size...